# C++ Null Child Exception

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

For an assignment, I have to implement a Red-Black tree. While implementing it, I ran into an issue in one of the rotation methods because a child node was null (right child of rotating node in left rotation). I was wondering if there was a try catch exception type block for this? Being fairly new to C++, I'm still learning how error catching is actually implemented, so I appreciate your help. If there's some other way I should be doing it, please let me know.

Comment: No, dereferencing nullptr is just undefined behavior, there's no guaranteed exception. Just check before doing so.

Comment: You need to design your code so that it never dereferences null.